# Unable to have the methods in one class completely run in main method when called by a class that extends first class

Tags: java

first class built. I think my problems lie within this first class. But i am unable to get the statement to print  to the main program when method is called. I am new to java came from perl. Ive tried returning values associated with dmg and blk but the complier says they were never intitialized.

```
import java.util.Random;

/*****************************************************************************
*   roll - rolls the dice.                           *
*   getDice1 - returns value of dice one.                    *
*   getDice2 - returns value of dice two.                    *
*   getTotal - returns the sum value of both dice.               *
*                                        *
*                                        *
*****************************************************************************/


//global variables for use throughout class.
public class Options {
    int dice1;
    int dice2;
    int dmg;
    int blk;
    int health = 100;
    Random randm = new Random();

    public Options() {
        roll();
        Attack();
        Block();
    }

    public void roll() {
        dice1 = randm.nextInt(6)+1;
        dice2 = randm.nextInt(6)+1;
    }   

    public int getTotal() {
        return dice1 + dice2;
    }

//switch statement used to compare the value of the roll to the determined value of attack.
    public protected Attack() {
        dice1 = randm.nextInt(6)+1;
        dice2 = randm.nextInt(6)+1;
        getTotal();
        int dmg;
        switch (getTotal()) {
            case 1: dmg = 2;
                    break;
            case 2: dmg = 3;
                    break;
            case 3: dmg = 4;
                    break;
            case 4: dmg = 5;
                    break;
            case 5: dmg = 6;
                    break;
            case 6: dmg = 7;
                    break;
            case 7: dmg = 8;
                    break;
            case 8: dmg = 9;
                    break;
            case 9: dmg = 10;
                    break;
            case 10: dmg = 11;
                    break;
            case 11: dmg = 12;
                    break;

        }
    }
// switch statement is used to compare the roll of dice to determine the value of blk.
    public protected Block() {
        dice1 = randm.nextInt(6)+1;
        dice2 = randm.nextInt(6)+1;
        getTotal();
        int blk;
        switch (getTotal()){
            case 1: blk = 2;
                    break;
            case 2: blk = 3;
                    break;
            case 3: blk = 4;
                    break;
            case 4: blk = 5;
                    break;
            case 5: blk = 6;
                    break;
            case 6: blk = 7;
                    break;
            case 7: blk = 8;
                    break;
            case 8: blk = 9;
                    break;
            case 9: blk = 10;
                    break;
            case 10: blk = 11;
                    break;
            case 11: blk = 12;
                    break;
        }
    } 
// determination whether or not the user has lost health or remains at current health.
    public void setHealth(){
        health = 100;

    }

    public int getHealth(){
        if (dmg >= blk){
            System.out.println("The attack hit for" + dmg);
            return health - dmg;
        } 
        else if (dmg < blk){
            System.out.println("The attack was blocked");
            return health;
        }
        return health;
    }

}
```

then created character class to that i wanted to access the option methods.

```
public class Character extends Options {
    String name;

    public Character(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public void setHealth(){
    }

    public int getHealth(){
        return health;
    }

    public int Attack(){
        return dmg;
    }

    public int Block(){
        return blk;
    }
}
```

Then final in the main program I dont believe the dice fro om options class are actually rolling a value because the print statements i put in the main are the only thing that print out. I even let it run for a full 30 mins last night without the sleep to just see if the logic kept coming up with more blocks vs attacks. but no dice it didnt complete at any point.

```
public class Game{

    public static void main(String args[]){

//Constructor for the two separate characters.
        Character monster = new Character("monster");
        Character hero = new Character("hero");

        monster.setHealth();
        hero.setHealth();
        System.out.println("Health has been set to 100.");

        while (monster.getHealth() != 0 || hero.getHealth() !=0) {
            try{
                System.out.println("Monster is set to Attack!");
                monster.Attack();

                Thread.sleep(500);

                System.out.println("Hero attempts to block");
                hero.Block();

                Thread.sleep(500);

                System.out.println("Hero attempts to Attack");
                hero.Attack();

                Thread.sleep(500);

                System.out.println("Monster attempts to Block");
                monster.Block();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        if (monster.getHealth() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Hero defeated the monster!!!!");
        } 
        else if (hero.getHealth() == 0 ){
            System.out.println("Monster has defeated hero!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

i had to use thread sleep as a way to make sure i wasnt missing if the lines from the options class were being missed in printing because the main program ran  way to fast.

Comment: int dmg = 0; int blk = 0; avoids the compiler's nagging. Make sure that the switch really covers all alternatives. Add a default: branch (with a throw new IllegalStateException()) to catch the unexpected.

Comment: The amount of flaws in this makes it too broad.  You need to research the fundamentals of OOP.  To give you a few tips here, I would move all of the stuff in `Options` and put it in `Character`, because the use of a child class here does not make sense.  Then you need to change most of your methods to interact with another character.  I.e. `monster.Attack(hero);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Attack()` and `Block()` need return types and cannot be both public *and* protected.
- There is already a Java class called `Character`. You should rename your class.  In fact, your Character class is superfluous.  The name attribute can be stored in the parent class and all the return statements can go in the parent methods.
- Because you are overriding the `Options` `Attack()` and `Block()` methods in your `Character` class, the parent method is not being called; you need to call it using `super.Attack()` or `super.Block()`.  But again, this child class is superfluous.
- You shouldn't be calculating damage/health in the `getHealth()` method.  Accessor methods should only be used for accessing attributes.  Use the mutator method (`setHealth()`) for changing the value of `health` and doing your calculations.
- Your call to `getTotal()` before your `switch` statement is unnecessary because you don't save the return value.
- You really don't need those sleep calls.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you think `Options()` is never initialized is because your `Character` constructor sets the name for your character, but it doesn't call the constructor for `Options`. So it never is initialized, or more specifically, all the values default to zero. (*You'd want to call `super();`*)

However, as @chancea said in a comment, there are actually a lot of errors in your code. Some quick things I'll mention:

-Options seems like you would want the dice to be re-rolled each time you want to Attack or Block, but it will be set just once when the object is created.

-You are calling `getters` such as `hero.Attack()` which just returns an `int`. You don't do anything with this call, you just get the value and then discard it.

-`getHealth()` is what is doing the damage to your character. It subtracts your character's health from its own attack and defense, with no regard to the opponent's attack or defense.